# Convert MySQL (JSON) Query Into Laravel Eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to convert a MySQL query (having mysql-json functions in it) into a Laravel Eloquent query. Below is my Mysql query. I have to build this eloquent query in laravel version 5.3. Tried and stuck at json functions

MYSQL Query :

```
SELECT  id FROM `house_json`  WHERE JSON_CONTAINS( JSON_EXTRACT(construction_json, "$.house.room[*].window"), '"Removed"' ) AND form_id=5 AND action_date BETWEEN '2020-05-25' AND '2020-05-27'
```

Eloquent Query :

```
$data_query = HouseData::select('house_json.id as ID')
->where('house_json.form_id',5)
->whereBetween('house_json.action_date', ['2020-05-25', '2020-05-27']) ->whereRaw('json_contains("json_extract("house_json.construction_json", "$.house.room[*].window")", '"Removed"')')
->get();
```

sample JSON (which is stored into table field named - construction_json) :

```
{
  "visit_date": "2020-05-25",
  "operative_name": "Peter",
  "tenant_name": "Denny",
  "id": "433",
  "house": {
    "room": [
      {
        "appliance_id": "72329",
        "landlord": "Yes",
        "location_id": 4,
        "location_name": "Back Hall",
        "status": "Removed",
        "comment": "",
        "reason": "Landlord denied"
      },
      {
        "appliance_id": "72330",
        "landlord": "Yes",
        "location_id": 4,
        "location_name": "Kitchen",
        "status": "Completed",
        "comment": "",
        "reason": ""
      }
    ],
    "other_detail": {
      "pipework_done": "Yes",
      "paperwork_done": "No",
      "general_comments": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you have so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I've converted query as : $data_query = HouseData::select('house_json.id as ID')
                ->where('house_json.form_id',5)
                ->whereBetween('house_json.action_date', ['2020-05-25', '2020-05-27'])
                ->whereRaw('json_contains("json_extract("house_json.construction_json", "$.house.room[*].window")", '"Removed"')')
                ->get();                                                                                                              and I'm stuck at json_contains and json_extract part, I have to build this query in laravel version 5.3

Comment: Nice. Would you please edit your question with that code? Reading it with proper formatting is a lot easier. Also, some sample JSON data might also help understanding your question.

Comment: @JorisJ1 I have updated question with more details. Sample json is what I stored into table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this I had the same issue earlier I solved as below.

```
$data_query = HouseData::select('house_json.id as ID')->
where('house_json.form_id', 5)->
whereBetween('house_json.action_date', ['2020-05-25', '2020-05-27'])->
whereRaw('JSON_CONTAINS(
    JSON_EXTRACT(
        house_json.construction_json,
        "$.house.room[*].window"),
    "Removed")')->
get();
```